# How to do a division sum with a whole number as an anwer

Tags: javascript

I am working on a maths quiz but I have come across a big problem.
The whole script runs great up until you choose division. The sum itself works fine but I have been trying to make it only give questions with whole numbers as answers.

Notes:
-All variables that are not declared HAVE been declared
-It is something wrong with the while loop (I think)

```
    //level 4
else if(level==4){
    alert(name + ", welcome to level 4 - Division!\nI will give you a sum and you must give me the answer. It's simple!");
    alert("For every one you get wrong, you lose one of your 3 lives. For every one you get right, you gain a point!");
    while(lives>0){
        var correctFloorAns = 1;
        var correctAns = 2;
        while(correctAns==correctFloorAns){
            alert("hi")
        }
        {
            primaryNumber = random(200);
            primaryNumber = primaryNumber * 1;
            secondaryNumber = random(200);
            secondaryNumber = secondaryNumber * 1;
            correctAns = primaryNumber / secondaryNumber;
            correctAns = correctAns * 1;
            correctFloorAns = Math.floor(correctAns);
        }
        playerAns = prompt(name + ", here is your sum: " + primaryNumber + " divided by " + secondaryNumber + "\n" + correctAns + "\n" + correctFloorAns);
        if(playerAns==correctAns){
            alert("Well done " + name + "! You got it right!");
            points = points + 1;
        }
        else{
            alert("Nope! You got it wrong");
            lives = lives - 1;
        }
        alert("You are now on " + lives + " live(s) and " + points + " point(s)!");
    }
    {
        alert("You died on " + points + " points! You are clearly not very good at maths, " + name + "!\nI got " + (points + 100) + " points!!!");
    }
```

Thanks,
Reece C.

Comment: Where in your code are you trying to give questions with only whole number answers?

Comment: With the Math.floor of 'correctAns' that is assigned to a variable. If it is the same as 'correctAns' then it will proceed. If else, it will get another random number.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote this :

```
    while(correctAns==correctFloorAns){
        alert("hi")
    }
    {
        primaryNumber = random(200);
        primaryNumber = primaryNumber * 1;
        secondaryNumber = random(200);
        secondaryNumber = secondaryNumber * 1;
        correctAns = primaryNumber / secondaryNumber;
        correctAns = correctAns * 1;
        correctFloorAns = Math.floor(correctAns);
    }
```

The code in the second block { } won't be executed in the while loop, it's executed only once.

I think what you wanted to write is this :

```
while(correctAns==correctFloorAns){
// I advise you to comment your alert once your debug is done, it will be very annoying
        alert("hi");
        primaryNumber = random(200);
        primaryNumber = primaryNumber * 1;
        secondaryNumber = random(200);
        secondaryNumber = secondaryNumber * 1;
        correctAns = primaryNumber / secondaryNumber;
        correctAns = correctAns * 1;
        correctFloorAns = Math.floor(correctAns);
    }
```

Cheers

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize that... How do I make it loop?

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but then 'primaryNumber' and 'secondaryNumber' are undefined... I had that error before...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone! Sadly, the scripts you gave me didn't work but I have found a solution! Here it is:

```
        var wrong = true
        //creates a random sum and loops until answer is a whole number bigger that 0
        while (wrong){
            primaryNumber = random(200);
            primaryNumber = (primaryNumber * 1) + 1;
            secondaryNumber = random(200);
            secondaryNumber = (secondaryNumber * 1) + 1;
            correctAns = primaryNumber / secondaryNumber;
            correctAns = correctAns * 1;
            correctFloorAns = Math.floor(correctAns);
            if(correctAns==correctFloorAns){
                wrong = false
            }
        }
```